# Hudson - SCM Polling configuration to detect revision changes of the subprojects

Tags: svn, version-control, hudson

I've a maven project which has two sub-projects which is defined using svn:externals in my SVN repository. In other words, I've a project hierarchy as follows :

-ParentProject

- Project
- Test-project

When I configured my hudson job, I only entered my parent project's SVN address.When I trigger the build manually I am able to check out all hierarchy and able to run all maven goals.

So now, I want to configure a SCM polling mechanism for my builds, so when I commit code (especially subprojects) a build would be triggered. The problem is SCM polling looks at the revision number of my parent project and it does not detect my sub-projects revision changes.

Is there any way to force hudson to look at also my subprojects revision changes? Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify several repository URLs and put them in appropriate places. For example:

**Parent Project:**

*Repository URL:*

```
svn://server/repoparent/trunk
```

*Local module directory:*

```
.
```

**Project:**

*Repository URL:*

```
svn://server/repoproject/trunk
```

*Local module directory:*

```
./somepath/project
```

**Test Project:**

*Repository URL:*

```
svn://server/repotest/trunk
```

Local module directory:

```
./somepath/project/tests
```

Then Hudson will react to changes in any of `repoparent/trunk`, `repoproject/trunk`, and  `repotest/trunk`.

Comment: My parent project already see my subprojects in its pom.xml as modules so when I trigger the build the job run all maven goals (parent-subprojects) are executed. So is it true adding all 3 svn repository to a job? PS : I've solved problem post-commit hook method (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin). Thanks for your reply

Comment: Yes, post-commit hook is probably the best option whenever you have easy access to it. The polling option will have an unnecessary checkout (it's not that bad, but still not as elegant). I think you should post your answer.